# Need high temperature edge-grip seal for flue

Tags: chimney

Part of the seal came off of my chimney cap.    I would like to replace it, however I can't find anything that is rated at a high temperature.  The closest I found was [this edge grip seal](https://www.zoro.com/trim-lok-trim-seal-epdm-25-ft-length-34-overall-width-style-trim-with-a-side-bulb-3062b3x164c-25/i/G4164240/?recommended=true).  However, it says max temp 158 F (70 C).  Any ideas about how I can replace this seal or where I can get a product that works for this purpose?  Thanks.

Edit:  the Zoro site has many images that don't go with the description.  I ended up buying this: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07KY3WXTQ?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KY3WXTQ)

Also, EPDM rubber is supposed to be able to withstand higher temperatures than ordinary rubber.

[image: Flue]
[image: Flue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like the correct one, I found it through my own googling and realised it was the same as yours.

I would contact them for your use case.  The style of chimney you have looks like the edges may not get very hot.  Otherwise, the rubber tube on top would have melted.

You could measure the operating temperature yourself if its safe for you to do so.

Comment: It probably is the same,  I wish it were more durable, but I'll give it a try.  Thanks.